# Por que devemos fechar esse tipo de pergunta?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Recententemente um usuário fez essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210701/configurar-dns-bind9-debian).

E logo após ela foi sinalizada para o fechamento, o pessoal que votou para fechar marcou fora do escopo, eu após tentar ajudar o AP, percebi que era um erro de digitação e também marquei para fechar.

Entretanto fica a dúvida:

Se temos as tags `Linux e Debian` relevantes ao que foi perguntado, e o AP colocou todas as informações relevantes para o que ele queria, ainda assim devemos fechar este tipo de pergunta?

**Edit**

*Só não entendo, por que os arquivos de configuração que por sua vez, fornecem parâmetros e definições de inicialização, que serão usados posteriormente, pelos "programas" propriamente ditos,não entram no escopo de programação. Uma vez que .htaccess, as definições do Apache, Json e outros também fornecem apenas parâmetros para os programas e eu vejo sempre que são perguntas bem aceitas...*

E ainda um comentário que se diz retórico (que está mais para irônico), tão bem votado.

Parece que minha pergunta é sem sentido.

Mas em comunidade nem tudo faz sentido.

Comment: É sobre programação? :p

Comment: você viu a pergunta? @DanielGomes

Comment: Minha pergunta foi retórica.

Comment: Para este tipo de pergunta eu sugeria o [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) q é mais especifico ou o [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) ou até mesmo o [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). A pergunta do OP não esta ligada com desenvolvimento ou programação. Na info das duas tags ilustra os cenários q elas devem ser usadas.

Comment: @DanielGomes retórica, qual o sentido?

Comment: @gato concordo que são mais específicos, mas isso não quer dizer (não sei, minha opinião ) que podendo ser respondida por estar bem detalhada , deva ser fechada, mas é programação também... É um problema que pode ser reproduzido...

Answer (score 7):

Não é dentro do escopo do site SO-pt e nem mesmo tolerado. Há casos como Apache, htaccess, etc, que são tolerados mesmo não sendo específicos sobre programação, mas são tolerados por serem ferramentas de "desenvolvimento" de aplicativos. O seu caso é sobre o bind que é redes. Network é um tema específico separado do contexto de "programação" do SO-pt que é específico para development. Desenvolvimento de aplicativos.

Conforme comentaram, é um tema para serverfault ou network engineering.

Se analisarmos bem, quase tudo pode ser programação. Fazendo uma analogia, um simples ato de sair de casa e ir numa padaria é programação. Você programa o seu cérebro para ir naquele local e já pensa nas condicionais como:

"se não levar dinheiro suficiente, vou perder tempo"

"se não trancar a casa, pode ser invadida"

"se sair de tenis caro, posso ser assaltado na rua"

O mesmo se dá com o assunto linux/bind. O bind é também programação, mas é específico para redes. Não é programação para desenvolvimento de aplicativos. Usando o bind você não cria aplicativos.

Claro que se a pergunta tivesse outro contexto, por exemplo, como alterar configuração do bind por linha de comando via PHP?

Nesse caso seria aceito porque o foco está no PHP e poderia usar uma API, SSH, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Da *tag* [linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux):

> Se a sua pergunta não tem nada a ver com APIs do Linux ou comportamento específico do Linux você não deve usar essa tag.

Por esse motivo, fui lá e removi a *tag* da pergunta.

Eu não tenho conhecimento suficiente sobre *Debian* para determinar se a pergunta é específica sobre *Debian* ou não. Mas me parece que é um problema de configuração de sistema operacional, não de uso de API's ou algo parecido.

Nós aceitamos perguntas sobre *.htaccess*, *json* e similares porque os valores nesses arquivos de configuração podem ser lidos e utilizados por aplicações que nós fazemos. Não me parece ser o caso da pergunta. Eu a manteria fechada.

Comment: Veja, a pergunta não é sobre Debian ou Linux especificamente, e sim sobre o Bind, que é um programa. Que do mesmo modo que outras aplicações, também precisa de parâmetros tal qual qualquer aplicação por vc mencionada,

Comment: Bind9, certo? Se o OP estiver desenvolvendo com a API do Bind9, eu acho que a pergunta deve ser reaberta. Caso contrário, deve continuar fechada.

Comment: Então, o que acha de ver a questão e confirmar o que realmente se passa e aí dar um ponto de vista mais objetivo? Veja, não estou te desafiando ou algo parecido, apenas creio que o problema desse fechamento é justamente esse, foi marcada sem a devida observação.

Comment: Eu observei. Não vi nada sobre programação.

Comment: Então ok, preciso rever meu conceito de programação, obrigado pelo seu ponto de vista.