# Qual é o escopo do termo programação?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Programação é apenas o trecho do código feito em uma linguagem específica, ou se propaga aos arquivos de configuração também?

Por exemplo:

Tendo eu uma dúvida sobre certos parâmetros do arquivo `php.ini` cabe a dúvida ao escopo de programação?

Comment: Não parece ser sobre programação exatamente cai melhor em configuração de ferramentas para desenvolvimento.

Comment: O escopo do StackOverflow [não é limitado somente a programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @rray entendo, entretanto sendo indispensável à programação certos parâmetros do `php.ini`, além de configurações, ele faria parte também do escopo de programação?

Comment: @MagicHat sim porque os scripts php dependem do "interpretador php" (o executável) que este por sua vez depende **exclusivamente** das configurações (php.ini) para variar o seu comportamento, então sim, é dentro do escopo ;)

Answer (score 3):

De uma maneira bem resumida e direta, o escopo do termo "programação" do site SO-pt é "desenvolvimento de software".

Para elucidar um pouco mais, essa sua pergunta tem relação com outra que fizeste: [Por que devemos fechar esse tipo de pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6077/4793)

Aa página de ajuda define com clareza

> - um problema específico de programação
> - um algoritmo de software
> - ferramentas comuns entre programadores
> - problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software
> - dúvidas teóricas sobre conceitos e práticas aplicados ao desenvolvimento de software

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta,  a dificuldade que estou encontrado para compreender é a seguinte: Para "desenvolver um software" eu preciso de um ambiente e outra infinidade de ferramentas, então vou tomar como exemplo(já que achou pertinente citar) a questão sobre o bind, que é um software, na pergunta em questão o AP colocou alguns arquivos de configurações essenciais para o bom funcionamento do software, entretanto muitos membros da comunidade afirmam não ter relação com "programação", daí a pergunta: Então o escopo de "programação" não se propaga as configurações das ferramentes bem como os...

Comment: ... arquivos de configurações relevantes ao funcionamento do software?

Comment: Conforme citado várias vezes, o bind é especifico do âmbito de redes. Você não usa o bind para desenvolver softwares, sacou? O bind é uma ferramenta de infraestrutura de redes.

Comment: Entendo, mas ele é um software, da camada da aplicação, não infraestrutura, achei que entraria no escopo...
Mas legal, mais uma vez obrigado pelo seu ponto de vista ou qual respeito, mas não concordo.

Comment: Deixando claro, não é questão de concordar comigo. Isso é norma do site. Quando comecei aqui no final de 2014, me orientaram a interpretar dessa forma e só estou passando para frente. Se você tem uma opinião, proposta, etc, fique a vontade para abrir discussão. É para isso que serve o meta. E mais uma vez, não importa se bind é um software. O ponto é que com o bind você NÃO CRIA um sofware. Por isso fica fora de escopo e isso está claro na resposta. Procure ler com calma entender. O que é do âmbito de redes não se encaixa aqui. É serverfault ou network engineering. Não temos serverfault-pt.

Comment: Acho que a questão vai um pouco além de criar ou não software, pq no fundo é uma questão de DNS, e ao meu ver tem tantas já no site (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Dns), por isso que não entendi o fechamento como fora do escopo da pergunta citada, e continuo tentando entender o escopo de programação...

Comment: Pensando bem para mim tudo que está na camada da aplicação, deveria entrar no escopo do site...

Comment: Nem tudo é perfeito. Algumas do resultado de busca deveriam estar fechadas como fora do escopo. Muitas vezes essas perguntas fora de escopo acabam escapando, é normal. E aquela sobre o python, é válida, é um exemplo de caso tolerável pois o tema é python, conforme expliquei na resposta esse tipo de situação. Outras nem vou ler porque é uma das duas coisas. Ou é fora do escopo e deixaram passar despercebido ou possui um contexto que a valide (tolerável). No seu caso é serverfault e network. Não tem nada com api ou com contexto de desenvolvimento de software envolvido.

Comment: e qual o sentido da tag DNS? Não querendo estender como discussão, mas para eu entender... Muda o escopo se a dúvida sobre DNS é tratada com uma linguagem específica?

Comment: Abra nova pergunta especifica indagando sobre a existência da tag. Pois aí já torna estenso demais para o tema aqui proposto. Mas já te adianto que o importante é o contexto, a interpretação do corpo da pergunta. As tags são formas de organizar e pesquisar com mais precisão sobre o que está dentro do contexto, seja ele válido ou não. Se vc perguntar sobre dns e tão somente sobre dns, será fechado como fora do escopo pois isso é redes... kkkk  OMG..  Desculpe, já gastei tempo demais aqui e cada comentário parece um loop infinito.

Comment: Ah sei lá, DNS não é redes...

Comment: > problemas práticos e bem definidos que dizem respeito ao desenvolvimento de software

o problema aqui é que todos temos uma diferente opinião sob o que é "bem definido" - eu vejo isso pelos meus flags que são rebatidos e rejeitados. 

Não que fique piursso, mas há que haver uma definição de "bem definido", eu acho que meter um link para um site e "como eu faço isso?" não é nada bem definido

Comment: Você pode abrir nova discussão sobre algo específico que lhe acometeu. Se acha que houve má interpretação em alguma postagem sua, pode abrir no meta um novo tópico e receberá feedback de mais pessoas. @MoshMage

Comment: @DanielOmine nem tanto, suponho que não seja uma pessoa e sim o voto de várias que não têm a mesma opinião que eu - e tem que se viver com isso. Mas haver *claridade* nas definições é preciso

Comment: Não sei do que está falando. Por isso, se quer se expressar de forma mais clara, sugiro um novo post. Evite conversa paralela ao assunto aqui, por favor.